# How to make nested comment system express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement multi-level comment output. That is, there is a comment, it can have answers, answers can also have answers, and so on. Now i'm using SQLite.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Model

```
const Comments = sequelize.define('Comment', {
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
})

Comments.hasMany(Comments, { as: 'Replies', foreignKey: 'parentId' })
```

Service

```
async getCommentByID(id) {
    try {
      return await comments.findByPk(id, {
        include: [
          {
            model: comments,
            as: 'replies',
            include: {
              model: comments,
              as: 'replies',
              include: {
                model: comments,
                as: 'replies',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    } catch (e) {
      throw createHttpError(500, e)
    }
  }
```

I want to get one general coomment with all their nested comment and their nested comments? and so on, but this way I can only reach the second level of nesting, but I would like to automate this somehow.

Comment: This is a well known problem with relational databases. Depending on which actual database you're using there might be a way to select an entire hierarchy, but you'll want to search the web a bit for this (well documented, lots-talked-about) problem =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm trying to find the solution all day? but for now i still can't find a solution, so I decided to ask a question

Comment: Do a search for your database name and "select hierarchy". You're going to find a lot of results, and almost certainly even a bunch of highly upvoted SO questions. Having said that: please tag your post with the database you're using. Because that matters.

Comment: Or “tree in sql” where “sql” is a db, orm, etc.

Comment: I don't see that you added a condition about a certain comment? Do you really want t get them all at once?

Comment: @Anatoly It's just a part of my application. In this service all i need is to get one comment by id with all their chlids and their childs and so on. I changed my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this is a well-known problem and there are many ways to solve it. But, since you are using Sequelize, a good option would be to use a plugin to handle complex queries around the commnets hierarchy.

A good option is *sequelize-hierarchy* ( [Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy), [GitHub](https://github.com/overlookmotel/sequelize-hierarchy)). It's even listed on Sequelize [official docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/resources/).

Adapting it to you use case, it's possible to define your comments model as:

```js
const Comments = sequelize.define('Comment', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  parentId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    hierarchy: true
  }
});
```

You could retrieve an entire comment tree with:

```js
const commentsTree = await Comments.findAll({ hierarchy: true });
```